# Android ADK - Working on a gamepad

Tags: android, keyboard, usb, arduino, adk

I am working on a new idea and the code is going very well, but I am facing some issues and need your help.

I have recently bought an old and broken gaming station at a ridicoulous price (I don't know the exact English word), and, as it is very old and broken, I had the idea to replace it with an Android OS (I have seen many Android USB sticks or [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)) and a TFT screen.

[image]

The Arduino and buttons wiring is working fine, and I can read the output when I press a button.

[image]

So, my next step will be to buy a USB Host shield similar to this one: http://www.circuitsathome.com/products-page/arduino-shields/usb-host-shield-2-0-for-arduino.

But now, I really would like to know how I can tell Android that this future device will act like a keyboard.

I will need to bind some buttons to the <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> arrow...

I also would like to bind some buttons to "home" or "back".

So, what are the practice to achieve that?

Will I need to create a custom keyboard?

All I can find is in *[USB Accessory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html)*, but there is not much information.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're expecting the Android device to do?  What inputs will you send to the device, what outputs will it generate?

Comment: I just want to send keystrokes to the Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will answer myself, Q&A style, after a whole night of search!

The only solution I have found is to turn my Arduino into a USB keyboard and that seems rather simple: http://hunt.net.nz/users/darran/weblog/b3029/

You have to flash an alternative firmware that will turn your arduuino into a USB keyboard.

hex file to flash and demo project on the link.

That means that I can programmatically send keystrokes to an Android via USB.

The only problem I am facing is the debounche that I need write myself and seems quite complicated.